# Redux - Removing entities from related state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a redux state of the following form, which is managed in slices using `combineReducers`:

```
interface AppState {
  foos: Foo[];
  bars: Bar[];
  bazs: Baz[];
}
```

These are related in the following way:
One `Foo` has many `Bar`. One `Bar` has many `Baz`. Their structures are as follows:

```
interface Foo {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface Bar {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  fooId: string;
}

interface Baz {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  barId: string;
}
```

I have the regular thunks/actions setup for each part of the state, i.e `DELETE_FOO_REQUEST`, `DELETE_FOO_FAILURE` `DELETE_FOO_SUCCESS` and other CRUD options for each of the entities.

My delete foo thunk looks like this:

```
function deleteFoo(fooId) {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(deleteFooRequest());

    await api.deleteFoo(fooId);

    dispatch(deleteFooSuccess(fooId);
    // omitted error handling for brevity
  }
}
```

The thing is: **when I delete a `Foo` on my api/backend it also deletes all related `Bar`s and `Baz`s**. Now how do I handle this while using `redux-thunk` conventions?

Do I create more actions of the form `DELETE_BARS_FOR_FOO` and dispatch those in the same thunk? Or do I reuse `DELETE_BAR_SUCCESS` and use it in a loop?

**Option A**

```
function deleteFoo(fooId) {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(deleteFooRequest());

    await api.deleteFoo(fooId);

    const barIds: string[] = selectBarsForFoo(fooId);

    dispatch(deleteFooSuccess(fooId);
    dispatch(deleteBarsForFoo(fooId);

    for (const barId of barIds) {
      dispatch(deleteBazForBar(barId));
    }

    // omitted error handling for brevity
  }
}
```

**Option B**

```
function deleteFoo(fooId) {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(deleteFooRequest());

    await api.deleteFoo(fooId);

    const barIds: string[] = selectBarsForFoo(fooId);

    dispatch(deleteFooSuccess(fooId);
    for (const barId of barIds) {
      dispatch(deleteBarSuccess(barId));
    }

    // followed by a similar loop for the bazs of each bar
    // omitted error handling for brevity
  }
}
```

In option B case I am reusing an action meant for something else technically. In both actions I'm dispatching in a loop which would impact performance as well. I am using react-redux however and can use the [`batch()`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch) api so no worries there.

Are these my only two options while using `redux-thunk` or is there a superior/conventional way of going about this?

Comment: You can also delete related Foo data in deleteFooSuccess reducer.

Comment: The data isn't nested and I am using combineReducer so the component state doesn't have access to other states

Comment: I missed that, you could still have multiple combine reducers, one to handle Appstate and one that handles Foo, Bar and Baz separately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complicating your actions is it an option to just deal with this in your reducer (as suggested in comments). The following way you can still use combineReducers but have a combined reducer that gets `{foo,bar,bas}` as state:

```
const fooBarBaz = combineReducers({
  foo:fooReducer,
  bar: barReducer,
  baz:bazReducer,
});
const combined = (state,action)=>{
  //handle foo remove success action, state is {foo,bar,baz}
}
export default function reducer(state,action){
  return combined(fooBarBaz(state,action),action)
}
```

Comment: This is viable, I have never seen examples of it being done this way, is this a common approach?

Comment: @user3690467 Even if you don't see it much it may be simpler in your case, Fact is that combineReducers just creates a reducer function `(state,action)=>newState` and you can have as many reducers as you see fit. Most examples split state with combineReducers in slices that can be separated, you need to separate only some and (Foo, Bar or Baz) but need certain actions to get {Foo,Bar, Bas}